# How to extend a Vue component with slots

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I want to get a third party library component, add one element more and use this third party with the same way as always.

Example:

```html
<third-party foo="bar" john="doe" propsFromOriginalLibrary="prop">
  <template v-slot:top=v-slot:top={ props: test }>
    Some text on third-party component slot
  </template>
</third-party>
```

Want to code as:

```html
<my-custom-component propsFromOriginalLibrary="prop">
  <template v-slot:top={ props: test }>
    Some text on third-party component slot
  </template>
</my-custom-component>
```

And both examples work the same way. I was able to get all the props by using:

```html
<third-party v-bind="$attrs">
```

but not sure about how to handle the slots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:

**`my-custom-component` template:**

```html
<template>
  <third-party v-bind="$attrs">
    <template v-slot:top="slotProps">
      <slot name="top" v-bind="slotProps"></slot>
    </template>
  </third-party>
</template>
```

What's happening:

1. Inserting the third party component and `v-bind` `$attrs`
2. Referencing its `top` slot
3. Custom component has a slot which is passed into third's slot
4. Custom slot has the same name so it can be `v-slot` the same way from a parent
5. Custom slot `v-bind`s all 3rd party `slotProps` to pass out to a parent

You can use a `v-for` to avoid the need for hard-coding an inner template for each slot. For example if you wanted to expose two slots, `top` and `bottom`:

```html
<template>
  <third-party v-bind="$attrs">
    <template v-for="slot in ['top','bottom']" v-slot:[slot]="slotProps">
      <slot :name="slot" v-bind="slotProps"></slot>
    </template>
  </third-party>
</template>
```

Demo:

```js
Vue.component('third-party', {
  props: ['background'],
  template: `
  <div class="third" :style="{ background }">
    3rd party slot:
    <div class="third-slot">
      <slot name="top" :props="props"></slot>
    </div>
  </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      props: 'Third party Prop'
    }
  },
})

Vue.component('my-custom-component', {
  template: `
  <div>
    <component is="third-party" v-bind="$attrs">
      <template v-for="slot in ['top']" v-slot:[slot]="slotProps">
        <slot :name="slot" v-bind="slotProps"></slot>
      </template>
    </component>
  </div>
  `
})

/***** APP *****/
new Vue({
  el: "#app"
});
```

```css
.third,.third-slot {
  padding: 10px;
}
.third-slot {
  background: #cccccc;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <third-party background="#eeeeff">
    <template v-slot:top="{ props: test }">
      Some text on third-party component slot
      <div>{{ test }}</div>
    </template>
    
  </third-party>

  <my-custom-component background="red">
    <template v-slot:top="{ props: test }">
      Some text on third-party component slot
      <div>{{ test }}</div>
    </template>
  </my-custom-component>
</div>
```

**Fun:** You could even make the wrapped component dynamic like `<component :is="thirdpartyName">` and the slot name array too; even passing this info in from outside for a fully generic wrapper.  But there's no need for that here